# How to use external package in Jupyter of Azure Spark

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to add an external package in Jupyter of Azure Spark.

```
%%configure -f
{ "packages" : [ "com.microsoft.azure:spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11:2.0.4" ] }
```

Its output :

```
Current session configs: {u'kind': 'spark', u'packages': [u'com.microsoft.azure:spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11:2.0.4']}
```

But when I tried to import:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils
```

I got an error:

> The code failed because of a fatal error:     Invalid status code '400'
>   from
>   http://an0-o365au.zdziktedd3sexguo45qd4z4qhg.xx.internal.cloudapp.net:8998/sessions
>   with error payload: "Unrecognized field \"packages\" (class
>   com.cloudera.livy.server.interactive.CreateInteractiveRequest), not
>   marked as ignorable (15 known properties: \"executorCores\", \"conf\",
>   \"driverMemory\", \"name\", \"driverCores\", \"pyFiles\",
>   \"archives\", \"queue\", \"kind\", \"executorMemory\", \"files\",
>   \"jars\", \"proxyUser\", \"numExecutors\",
>   \"heartbeatTimeoutInSecond\" [truncated]])\n at [Source:
>   HttpInputOverHTTP@5bea54d; line: 1, column: 32] (through reference
>   chain:
>   com.cloudera.livy.server.interactive.CreateInteractiveRequest[\"packages\"])".
>
> Some things to try: a) Make sure Spark has enough available resources
>   for Jupyter to create a Spark context. For instructions on how to
>   assign resources see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=717038 b)
>   Contact your cluster administrator to make sure the Spark magics
>   library is configured correctly.

I also tried:

```
%%configure
{ "conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "com.microsoft.azure:spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11:2.0.4" }}
```

Got the same error.

Could someone point me a correct way to use external package in Jupyter of Azure Spark?

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue. It seems realted to different scala version for libraries that eventhub requires and livy manage

Answer (score 1):

If you're using HDInsight 3.6, then use the following. Also, be sure to **restart your kernel** before executing this:

```
%%configure -f
{"conf":{"spark.jars.packages":"com.microsoft.azure:spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11:2.0.4"}}
```

Also, ensure that your package name, version and scala version are correct. Specifically, the JAR that you're trying to use has changed names since the posting of this question. More information on what it is called now can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark.

Comment: Still not working, I got error "The code failed because of a fatal error:
 Session 9 unexpectedly reached final status 'dead'. See logs:
.
", But if I remove the config and restart, it has no errors.

Comment: This has happened to me when the JAR name and/or version number was wrong. Did you check the Jar name to ensure the names and the version numbers are correct? I mentioned in my answer that the JAR you are trying to add (EventHubs-spark) has changed names. Please see the GitHub repo I linked to for more details on the updated JAR name and version.

Comment: Here is what I have tried: %%configure -f 
{"conf":{"spark.jars.packages":"com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.1.6-SNAPSHOT"}} and "import org.apache.spark.eventhubs._",  I still got error message: "java.lang.Exception: No YARN application is found with tag livy-session-11-h64fyxzf in 120 seconds. Please check your cluster status, it is may be very busy."

Comment: Just curious, do I need download the library and upload to the corresponding storage account?

Comment: No. You don't need to download it. However, since you're getting an error saying the cluster is busy, I wonder if there are too many jobs running on your cluster. Have you checked the Yarn UI to see if your cluster has enough resources for the job?

Comment: I do not think so. Because I tried some simple file reading and it is fine. THe error only happens when you are trying to import the external library.

Comment: Did you try to import another library to see if it's this particular library that is giving you troubles?